# Readablility in RSpec tests/output

Tags: rspec, readability

I'm fairly new to using RSpec.  I'm wondering what the best practice is regarding test/output readability.  [Here I have two examples](http://pastebin.com/s3DFBrFH) of testing a class method.  The first has straightforwardly (?) readable tests, but the output is a bit ambiguous.  The second has verbose/redundant tests when read, but the output is very clear.

```rb
class StringTester
  def self.is_hello?(s)
    s == 'hello'
  end
end

RSpec.describe StringTester do
  # Tests are fairly readable in English...
  describe '::is_hello?' do
    it { expect(StringTester.is_hello?('hello')).to be_truthy }
    it { expect(StringTester.is_hello?('something else')).to be_falsey }
  end
end

# ...but the output is ambiguous without going back to look at the tests.
# Output:
# StringTester
#   ::is_hello?
#     should be truthy
#     should be falsey


RSpec.describe StringTester do
  # Tests are redundant when read in English...
  describe '::is_hello?' do
    it 'is true for "hello"' do
      expect(StringTester.is_hello?('hello')).to be_truthy
    end
    it 'is false for "something else"' do
      expect(StringTester.is_hello?('something else')).to be_falsey
    end
  end
end

# ...but the output is very straightfoward.
# Output:
# StringTester
#   ::is_hello?
#     is true for "hello"
#     is false for "something else"
```

So is one way considered a better practice than the other?

Comment: There is no single best practice, so any answer would be an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the second form is usually preferable because the `it` description allows you to explain the *rule* that's being tested. In your code above, it only looks like duplication because this is a very simple, contrived example.

Let's say you were testing code which checks if an input is positive:

`describe '#positive?' do
    it 'is true for numbers greater than zero' do
      expects(Foo.positive?(1)).to be_truthy
    end
    it 'is false for numbers less than zero' do
      expects(Foo.positive(-1)).to be_falsey
    end
  end`

The RSpec output then becomes more readable as it is describing the overall *behaviour* rather than just the output for individual examples.